# Store duration of song in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, time

What is the best way to store the duration of a song in a MySQL database?

I have two tables, *Albums* and *Tracks*. I want to be able to calculate the total duration of the album but **NOT** store it in the *Albums* table.

Each *track*, should therefore store its length in an appropriate format so that I can calculate this. I want to be able to add up all the track durations and display that on the 'album details' page. Is it best to store it as an integer and convert to a timestamp when needed or is it better/ok to store it directly in the database in the time format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to store a column depends on how you are going to use it.  Because your question doesn't specify what you will be doing with the lengths, any response is mostly speculation.

Here are several options:

1. Store the duration in units, probably as a floating point or decimal number.
2. Store the duration as a `datetime`.  This is preferable to `timestamp` because the `datetime` does not include time zone information.
3. Store the duration as a `time`.
4. Store the duration as a string representation.

The "best" method depends on what you are going to do with it.  If you are storing the duration *only* for output purposes, then (4) might be the best method.  If you are going to do a lot of adding up duration values, then (1) might be best.  If your durations are going to exceed one day, then (2) might be best.  And so on.

Comment: Thank you, I will go with option 1 so that I can calculate the sum of all tracks to give me an 'album length'.

Answer (score 3):

I would store the duration as the amount of seconds in a float format then do the appropriate conversion when I need the data. This will also make queries easier when comparing song lengths etc

Comment: When storing seconds, why `float` and not `int`?

Comment: @reformed yes, int would work better. Back when I made the comment the thought of using an int didn't come to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this would come down to personal preference, however you may also want to consider how these times will be used.

MySQL and many other programming languages have some great features built it to work with timestamps and date/times. If you might be doing calculations like "get the sum of all song lengths in this album", or "get the average length" then storing the times as Integers may make more sense.

If you're just dumping the times out in your application (or website), then maybe the MySQL Time format may be easier.